# Internal SSD compatible?

Tags: mac, hard-drive, ssd, mac-mini, compatibility

Since I was not able to find it out does anyone of you know if the following INTERNAL SSD will be compatible with my MacMini Late 2012 (the cheaper one)?

[Internal SSD from BestBuy](http://www.bestbuy.com/site/pny-optima-120gb-internal-serial-ata-iii-solid-state-drive-for-laptops/8191179.p;jsessionid=D122C287323385B1ECF953FB7C763F3F.bbolsp-app02-192?id=1219315690159&skuId=8191179&st=mac%20ssd&cp=1&lp=5)

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This SSD looks like it should work fine with a Mac Mini that has a SATA connection (which your Mac Mini does). It also claims to be compatible with Mac OS X.